# FailedToPerformActionsOnBlockedControlException By Coded UI Recording and Playback

Tags: coded-ui-tests

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHD4p.gif)

I am getting the above error. When i debug the Coded UI script. I Recorded closing a window by clicking on "X" and when i play back it is giving this error. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1x3GC.png)

When i try to drag the crosshair on to the Closing Button of the window ("X"). The Blue Rectangle is not identifying it but i am able to identify all other controls giving the blue color rectangle but not this. Anyone faced the same problem? what could be the solutions to it.

Comment: can you add a screenshot on what you are trying to close? Is this a winforms, wpf, store app or web? what is the nearest control you can locate using the crosshair?

Comment: I added two images you can click on Enter Image Description here link to see the screenshots. It's a winforms close(cross) button we trying to close.

Comment: I can not make anything out of the image you added. reason I asked for a screenshot is to see if it is really a standard windows control, or if this might be a custom control that is used from some vendor. if a button is custom drawn then it does not have a real window and then it is hard to get a real reference to the control. It really makes a big difference how a windows is created in how you can identify it and use UI automation on it.